# Ajax jQuery returning successfully after 10 seconds when it shouldn't

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, timeout, response

I've got a jQuery ajax call which goes of to the server backend.php script and told to sleep for 13 seconds (or more) before responding with a simple test message. What I'm seeing is the ajax success function triggering (with a 200 response observed in firebug) after 10 seconds with no actual response from the server. If I set the response delay to less than 10 seconds I get the response message perfectly.

Is this something you've seen before? Is there some default php timeout thing going on?

```
    ajaxcall = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "backend.php",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 30000,
    /* Timeout in ms. Default to 30000 (30 seconds) */
    data: "TimeStamp=" + TimeStamp,
    success: function(data) {

        if (data !== null) {
            $('#TextHistory').append(data.message);

            if (data.timestamp != 0)
            {
              TimeStamp = data.timestamp;
            }
        }
        setTimeout(
        waitForMsg, /* Request next message */
        5000 /* ..after 5 seconds, default to 5000*/ );
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        $('#TextHistory').append('<p>Error:' + errorThrown + '</p>');

        setTimeout('waitForMsg()',"15000"); /* milliseconds (15seconds) default to 15000 */
    }
});
```

}

..and on the server side i'm simply doing this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

sleep(13);   // Changing this to test it. Will only work if less than 10

   $When = date("H:i:s",strtotime("now"));

   $response["message"] = "<p>Small Test $When</p>";

    $response["timestamp"] = 123456789;

   echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely its timing out after 10 seconds

Place a call to `phpinfo()` on a blank page and see what the timouts are set to

Look at max_execution_time for one

It'll just need to be overriden in a php.ini file or in the PHP directly

Comment: @Dan Twining, Usually numbers regarding time are referring to **milliseconds**

Comment: ok, well...i tried setting "set_time_limit(35);" in my backend script and get the message "Warning: set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons in......" I've got a shared hosting account with streamline.net so i'm guessing there isn't anything I can do about it?

Comment: I am curious though as to why its timng out after 10 seconds when in the php info it says 30..hhhmmmm.

Comment: If your server won't let you sleep for more than 10 seconds, I would just use a setTimeout() on the Javascript side (or delay() for jQuery, depending how you're calling it) for ajaxcall.